# RuntimeException: The Facebook sdk must be initialized before calling activateApp

Tags: android, facebook

After having split my app into 2 different modules (a `module` and an  `application` one), I had to add `tools:node="replace"` in `<application>` node because I was having an issue with Manifest Merging (related to Facebook and Firebase).

Since I did this, everything works fine but my app now crashes at runtime with this exception: `The Facebook sdk must be initialized before calling activateApp`

However I'm initializing the app like this (in a class extending `Application`):

```
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); // this = instance of Application
```

I have changed absolutely nothing and it used to work fine before, but now I get this crash. I have no idea what to do... nothing found about this could help me.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT : here is the associated Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="package"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="package.permissions.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission android:name="package.permissions.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme"
        tools:node="replace" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider#############"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"

            android:exported="true"/>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you check and maybe post the merged manifest in Android Studio?

Comment: Hi, I just added it

Comment: have you tried  `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);`

Comment: It did work, but it's a bit strange since I didn't need this before, and this method is also deprecated... thanks anyway

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I solve it using the [update guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4x)

please, try change the method `onCreate` from your `MainApplication.java` to:

    `@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }`

Comment: yeah, it's weird that even when Facebook deprecated the `sdkInitialize` method we are forced to add it to avoid this crash.

Comment: What is cute is that the deprecation annotation is very informative:
`@Deprecated("")` :) And no info in docs.

Answer (score 1):

Even Facebook deprecated the **sdkInitialize()** method.

you need to add below code to solve this error.

```js
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```